# Screen ctrl+a key not working for going to start of line

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I recently started using screen:
ctrl+a key not working for going to start of line
How do I configure it? Is there a better alternative over screen?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>C-a</kbd> is the default screen command prefix. To get <kbd>C-a</kbd> in a shell, you need to press it twice.

To change the command prefix, specify the `escape` command in the `.screenrc` file; for example, I use

```
escape ``
```

which makes the backtick the command prefix. I use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` `` in the shell, but it's a recommended practice anyway.

Some people prefer `tmux` over `screen`.